# Altering Scala configuration for test purposes

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I want alter my programs configuration during tests to pick different database to test on. I want to pick a dummy db in mongo to don't worry about damaging my manual tests database and fabricate a behavior similar to Ecto's testing. (I know that they achieve that through transactions, but I think dropping mongo's db should be sufficient.

Have anyone tried to do similar things? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
Or can I even make Scala choose different configuration files based on arguments input? (for example choose test.conf when mode=test, choose prod.conf when conf passed etc..)

using Scala configuration (https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

Comment: this is about your config library, if your or your driver's is using typesafe config which is pretty common, you should just give a test config at `src/test/resources/application.conf` etc.

Comment: how do i do test config?

Comment: It depends which lib you are using. There is not a single way for all the Scala libs. You need to be much more precise to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Using scala configuration by typesafe(lightbend?)

Comment: Many libraries are using TypeConfig config, you need to be precise, and have a look at how TypeConfig is searching for the resources.